# Primefaces upade ui:include not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1.When I press button dynamically include page but it not working.I try below code:

**page.xhtml**

```
<f:subview id="userView">
<h:form id="userId">
<p:commandButton id="userButton" value="Import"
action="user.pageAction" update=":userView:dynamicPanel"/>
</h:form>
<p:panel id="dynamicPanel">
  <ui:include src="${BranchDetails.PagePath}" />
</p:panel>
</f:subview>
```

**pageClass.java**

```
public void pageAction()
{
pagePath="/pages/userMangement/userDetail.xhtml"
}
```

I try update facescontext and request context also but it not include page
**FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(":dynamicPanel");** and
**RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":dynamicPanel")**
I try replace (:dyanamicPanel to dynamicPanel) update but that also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You use action the wrong

```
<f:subview id="userView">
<h:form id="userId">
<p:commandButton id="userButton" value="Import"
action="user.pageAction" update=":userView:dynamicPanel"/>
</h:form>
<p:panel id="dynamicPanel">
  <ui:include src="${BranchDetails.PagePath}" />
</p:panel>
</f:subview>
```

correct

```
<f:subview id="userView">
<h:form id="userId">
<p:commandButton id="userButton" value="Import"
action="#{user.pageAction}" update=":dynamicPanel"/>
</h:form>
<p:panel id="dynamicPanel">
  <ui:include src="${BranchDetails.PagePath}" />
</p:panel>
</f:subview>
```